# Stack based VS heap based buffer overflow

Tags: heap-memory, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow

Why is heap-based buffer overflow difficult than stack-based? Also, what is the difference between them?

I know that memory is allocated dynamically in case of heaps but, is that it?

Comment: Are you asking why it's harder to diagnose buffer overruns that occur on the heap than it is to diagnose buffer overruns that occur on the stack?

Comment: I am talking from an intruder perspective. What makes it difficult to exploit a program on heap than a program on the stack? 
Is it just because of dynamic memory allocation in case of Heap? or are there any other factors? 
I am a beginner in this topic so, I am curious to explore.